# a poet and a writer OR a poet and writer - Which expression is correct?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Are there any rules for this phrases? I don't see the difference between these phrases.

① Although better known today as ***a poet and a writer***, Kelly wrote the lyrics to more than 534 popular songs.

② She was also ***a poet and writer***, publishing a number of soccer articles for the magazines.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The article is applied to both and thus you may omit if *if you want!*

> He was a poet and writer

However, you can also put the article again.

> He was a poet and a writer

[NGram shows both the usages.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20poet%20and%20writer%2C%20a%20poet%20and%20a%20writer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20poet%20and%20writer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20poet%20and%20a%20writer%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20poet%20and%20writer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20poet%20and%20a%20writer%3B%2Cc1)

Comment: NGram? That was a great tool. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Ngram does show both usages but the version with a single article seems to be more commonly used.

Comment: @Mari-LouA yes, it's visible there. In fact, I won't use it two times...but the reason here could be laziness ^-^